# Forcefully remove hover css effect of element inherited from remote css library

Tags: jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic UI library, and my `<tr>` table elements have a hover effect on them from the `"selectable"` class on the table.

But I would like to disable this hover on specific rows(when they enter edit mode) without having to edit the css files (As my scope is only html/javascript, I'm only trying to mend an old issue)

I tried using `pointer-events:none;` but in my case there are other buttons inside the `<tr>` and they got disabled

Javascript event on the rows :

```
$('body').on('click', '#edit_card table tbody tr .link.icon.edit', function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    switch_row_to_editing_mode(row);
  })
```

CSS styling from the element inspector :

[image]

Comment: Where's the "*[mcve]*" code? Which rows do you want to style, and not-style? What CSS did you try to enable this, where did it fail? *How* did it fail?

Comment: @DavidThomas well I just thought there was no need to tag this question with Jquery/Javascript and provide uneccessary context

Comment: Unnecessary context such as the HTML and CSS that applies to the elements you want to style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on how you distinguish what rows you want to disable the css on. Two options are adding a special class to the `<tr>` in the html or using JavaScript.

**Option 1**

Add a special class to the tr's and make your own css.

css:

```
.row_with_exception {
    // custom css
}
```

html:

```
<tr class='row_with_exception'></tr>
<tr class=''></tr>
<tr class='row_with_exception'></tr>
<tr class=''></tr>
```

**Option 2**

Use Javascript to update the styling on the rows.

First get the rows you want to remove the hover from.

```
elements = [...] // array of jquery elements
```

Then for each element add custom css using JQuery.

```
elements.map(function (el) {
   el.css(...)
}
```

Comment: So, to override the external css, do I just leave it blank? where you put "custom css"

Comment: No you will put the css you want on the item, I wasnt sure what changed you wanted but you could do `.row_with_exception:hover{ color: red }`

Answer (score 1):

Without editing the CSS files you will have to use inline CSS (not recommended) but the syntax would be:

```
<tr style="background: white !important">
```

...which would stop the colour altering on hover

Comment: You - almost certainly - don't need to add `!important` to an in-line style (and in almost every case I've ever seen `!important` tends to reflect something chaotic and terrible behind the scenes).

Comment: I thought it might be required to trump the :hover style in the CSS files. I don't recommend inline CSS or using !important (in general), but merely wanted to solve the OP's question, which I think this would. Albeit "double" inelegantly :)

Answer (score 1):

If what you wanted to avoid is changing the css will screw up your well done job, then try to add a new class instead and apply it to the specific rows you wanted to disable

Have you seen [CSS disable hover effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754497/css-disable-hover-effect)?