# How to get rid of inbuilt CSS that gets appended on hover?

Tags: css, safari

I am using Safari browser and I have buttons like this -

[image]

On hover these look like as below -

[image]

I haven't added any css from my side but on inspect element I got this-

```
button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #b2b2b2;
    border-left-color: #575757;
    border-right-color: #575757;
}
```

I want to make it look like same on hover or not hover. So I tried setting css as-

```
button:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-left-color: none;
    border-right-color: none;
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754497/css-disable-hover-effect/26755719

Comment: tried suggested ways, but it's not working

Comment: can you please create the snippet. that will be helpful to guide you.

Comment: on which browser you're getting this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```css
      button {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #b2b2b2;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #575757;;
    outline: none;
    padding: 15px 30px; 
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #333333;
  }
  button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #b2b2b2;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid #575757;;
    outline: none;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
  <button type="button">Prev</button>
  <button type="button">1</button>
  <button type="button">2</button>
  <button type="button">3</button>
  <button type="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: in safari background color is changing on click not on hover

Comment: hi Vikash Yadav mene change kar diya he pls check me code